# Selenium click() not working for microsoftEdge webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, microsoft-edge, webdriver-io

I've tried the standard

```
var elementForMs = driver.findElement(By.xpath(selector));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", elementForMs);
```

and

```
var elementForMs = driver.findElement(By.css(selector));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", elementForMs);
```

And there are simply cases where the element never responds to the click in Microsoft Edge 15.01563.

Comment: Does it work when you execute javascript directly in console after finding the element?

Comment: Yes. It works fine in the console.

Comment: Then try executing the javascript to find element as well. `driver.executeScript("document.getElementXXX().click()",);`

Comment: Well that seems pretty obvious...now. thx.

Comment: Use JSE isn't standard practice in Selenium automation. Why aren't you using Selenium clicks?

Comment: JeffC, because I have a function to handle retries. This code is nestled under other code. As you may be aware, or perhaps I am missing some clue, Microsoft Edge does not consistently support xpath selectors for .click(). In my case I delegate all my clicks, finds and sendkeys to a function which routes those interactions to the appropriate handle _based upon OS and browser_.

Comment: Using 16.16299 and the problem remains. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

In my case Selenium does get the element, and "visually" clicks it (the clicked element get the focus). But nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

Each driver has unique bugs. So somethings that work in Firefox, may not work in Chrome or so on. So the only way around is to find what works and use it. And if possible report the issue to the driver owner

In your case since finding the element and clicking on it doesn't work with

```
var elementForMs = driver.findElement(By.xpath(selector));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", elementForMs);
```

But works when you use javascript directly in console. that means you should execute the same in your code

```
driver.executeScript("document.getElementXXX().click()");
```

Comment: Tarun, I want to write one method that handles Microsoft, since it is such a problem child with regard to clicks. Is driver.executeScript("document.getElementXXX().click()"); preferred? Or am I best served to try catch/retry?

Comment: Depends on how often you see such issues. I don't use IE so can't comment. But I would use try catch if such instances are less. if they happen quite often then I would change approach of coding so it easier to re-use code and change approach for IE

Comment: @TarunLalwani why are you preaching bad-practices? Please stop making people use `executeScript()`. Also This is a WebdriverIO question, your answer will probably lead a lot of people astray. (it's **[.execute()](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/execute.html)**)

Comment: @iamdanchiv, I never said this is a best practice. If you have a issue, you would stop your work or rather use a workaround till the issue is fixed? Thanks for the feedback on execute will update it